# Building specifically for HTC phone

Tags: android, htc-hero

Greetings,

I am trying to generate android platform specifically for HTC Hero. I have followed the instructions described and built from trunk (I suppose):
http://source.android.com/download
http://source.android.com/documentation/building-for-dream

The problem is that there is no 'extract_files.sh' script. So what is the proper procedure to build for HTC hero now, or where can I find this file?

P.S.
I need to build the whole platform from scratch because we are going to run C++ application on it.

Comment: You would need to figure out yourself which hardware drivers to extract from the device (much like the Dream instructions show you which proprietary drivers need to be included).  However, if you get it to build, I imagine you will run into licensing issues if you want to start distributing this platform for use by others.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build the whole platform from the scratch to run a C++ application.

You can use the ndk. [Check this link.](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html)